# Does the implicit conversion of a literal to a class type happen at compile time?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to write a class that is closely related to integers, and because of that I included a conversion constructor with the form

```
constexpr example::example(const int &n);
```

My question is: if I subsequently define the function

```
void foo(example n);
```

and I use it like this

```
foo(3);
```

in my code, is the integer literal `3` converted in an instance of `example` at compile time?

If no, is there a way to obtain this behavior?

If yes, does that still happen if the constructor isn't explicitly declared as `constexpr`?

Comment: What's the real problem that you are trying to solve?

Comment: @RSahu the question is about if the value is converted at compile-time or run-time. Is that the question?

Comment: Sounds like you want [`consteval`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/consteval)

Comment: My understanding is that `3` must be converted to an instance of `example` at compile time only if the object is needed for defining compile time constants. Otherwise, it won't be converted.

Comment: I'm absolutely not sure, but I _think_ it won't be converted unless you do like @RSahu says. [example](https://godbolt.org/z/P6Ge17K3r)

Comment: @RSahu What if `example` is a complicated object with a slow constructor, and `foo(3);` is inside another function like `void bar(){foo(3); return;}`? `3` is going to be converted every time `bar` is invoked?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fact that the constructor is `constexpr` does not force the computation to happen at compile time. It only means that the constructor is eligible to be used within both constant expressions and non-constant expressions.

If on the other hand you declare the constructor `consteval`, then it means that *only* constant expressions are allowed to call that constructor. This in turn implies that every invocation of the constructor must be checked by the compiler to ensure that it is a constant expression (because, if it is not, the compiler must diagnose the violation). Since checking that something is a constant expression requires checking whether it contains any undefined behaviour, such checking is as difficult as actually evaluating the expression. Therefore, you can be assured that declaring a constructor (or any other function) `consteval` will ensure that the function will not be called at runtime: the compiler is allowed to generate code to re-evaluate it at runtime, but there is no reason why it would do so. The downsides of this approach are that, first, it becomes impossible to use the constructor in a non-constant expression, and second, constant expression evaluation is much slower than runtime evaluation, and you have to decide whether the increased compile times are worth it.

If you leave the constructor as `constexpr` then you can still force it to be called at compile time *in particular instances* by using a `constexpr` variable:

```
constexpr example ex = 3;  // evaluated at compile time
foo(ex);
```

This is a consequence of the fact that a `constexpr` variable is only allowed to be initialized by a constant expression.

Comment: What if I used a `consteval` user defined literal?

Comment: @ThePirate42 I think that would work. It's similar to a `consteval` constructor.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the answer by Brian Bi, it should be mentioned that compiler optimization *may* cause the evaluation to happen at compile time in your example.

Look at this compilation without optimization https://godbolt.org/z/EccGosc7n versus the same code compiled with `-O3`: https://godbolt.org/z/Kz51x4acK.

Comment: As a side note, using `-O2` generates exactly the same assembly as `-O3`, while using `-O1` generates almost the same assembly (zeroes out eax using `mov eax, 0` instead of `xor eax, eax`)